# Google Apps Script to format last cells in specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, powerapps

I am not very familiar with Google Sheets or Scripts.

I have a PowerApp that is continually adding cells to a Google Sheet. In the last few days, the Sheet has started adding an apostrophe to the data in two of my columns.

I can't have this sheet running slowly (as it will slow down the process in PowerApps), so I need a simple way of formatting these new cells, as they are added, to remove that apostrophe.

I was trying this script with the on-edit trigger;

```
function LoseApostrophe(){
FormatDate();
FormatID();
}

function FormatDate(){
var ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stats");
var cell = Sheet.INDEX(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>””),COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>””)));
cell.setDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}

function FormatID(){
var ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stats");
var cell2 = Sheet.INDEX(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>””),COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>””)));
cell2.setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

but I get a syntax error on the cell lines. I am trying to format the last cells in columns A and B. I have some blank cells at the start of the sheet so the data in these columns start at A8 and B8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is any trigger to catch these changes.  My guess is that you will have to poll and fix them with a regex periodically.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add that I was planning on running that script with the on-edit trigger so as soon as a new row is added, the two cells would be formatted to number and date.

Comment: onEdit only fires on user edits

Comment: When I check version history, it shows the user for the last edit as whoever has just used the PowerApp to update the sheet. Would that count as a user edit or would they have to actually have the google sheet open themselves? I think my main issue is not being able to figure out how to access those last cells in the script itself.

Comment: That is not a user edit

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused by the colon in `B2:B`, actually the following declarations are wrong:

```
var cell = Sheet.INDEX(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>””),COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>””)));
```

```
var cell2 = Sheet.INDEX(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>””),COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>””)));
```

Considering that the following lines look to be using Class Range methods, you should assign a Class Range object to `cell` / `cell2`. This could be done by using the Sheet.getRange() method, i.e.

```
var cell = sheet.getRange('B2:B');
```

Notes:

1. `setDateFormat` isn't a method of Class Range (AFAIK it doesn't exists a a built-in method in Google Apps SCript). Instead use `Range.setNumberFormat()`.
2. Curly quotes should not be used either in Google Apps Script / JavaScript and Google Sheets formulas for delimiting strings / text values. Replace them by straight quotes or straight apostrophes / single straight quotes, in other words, replace

   ```
   ””
   ```

   by

   ```
   ""
   ```
3. built-in functions like INDEX, FILTER, COUNTA and cell references like `B2:B` can't be in Google Apps Script.

Regarding the onEdit trigger, it will not be fired by the edits made by PowerApps as it's only triggered by edits done by the user through the Google Sheets user interface. Instead you might try to use the change installable trigger.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable